# What is the simple way to extend the use of array to prevent out of memory exception?

Tags: c#, arrays, out-of-memory

```
float[][, , ,] tempData = new float[30][, , ,];

private void InitTempData()
{
    const int FocusSize = 400;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            tempData[i] = new float[40, FocusSize, FocusSize, 5];
        }
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I need to use the tempData with array size of like this:

```
tempData[30][40, 400, 400, 5]
```

But what I have experienced so far, it will go `OutOfMemory` when I define new Array at size more than 100.

What the idea I think of is, I initialize four new Array with size of 100. And use the four new Array starting with different initial counter as per below:

```
float[][, , ,] tempData0 = new float[30][, , ,];
float[][, , ,] tempData1 = new float[30][, , ,];
float[][, , ,] tempData2 = new float[30][, , ,];
float[][, , ,] tempData3 = new float[30][, , ,];

private void InitTempData()
{
    const int FocusSize = 100;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            tempData0[i] = new float[40, FocusSize, FocusSize, 5];
            tempData1[i] = new float[40, FocusSize, FocusSize, 5];
            tempData2[i] = new float[40, FocusSize, FocusSize, 5];
            tempData3[i] = new float[40, FocusSize, FocusSize, 5];
        }
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

//Use the tempData0, tempData1, tempData2, and tempData3 with different initial counter
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < FocusSize; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < FocusSize; z++)
        {
            //Use tempData0 here
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    for (int x = FocusSize; x < FocusSize * 2; x++)
    {
        for (int z = FocusSize; z < FocusSize * 2; z++)
        {
            //Use tempData1 here
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    for (int x = FocusSize * 2; x < FocusSize * 3; x++)
    {
        for (int z = FocusSize * 2; z < FocusSize * 3; z++)
        {
            //Use tempData2 here
        }
    }
}
```

Is my above idea is the correct way of doing it? Or is there any other option to extend the use of array?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the way you're declaring those arrays will get you *arrays of jagged arrays*.

Comment: If you're sure this is exactly what you want to do, maybe you should try x64 targetted build?

Comment: it is doing at .net4.0. And I just found out if I do it at .net4.5, it can use the config like <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects> set to true.

Comment: If this is your accepted solution, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: this is not my accepted solution. I am asking is there any other magical way of doing it or is my way of doing it is the correct way of extending the use of array. This is my question.

Comment: Each of your multidimensional arrays (i.e. `float[40,400,400,5]`) requires 128 megabytes of contiguous memory. All told, you're allocating slightly more than 12.8 gigabytes of memory for 100 arrays. Do you have that much memory available on your computer?

Comment: You can increase the size of your paging file, which will probably allow you to allocate the memory. But then your performance will suffer. You'll have to find some way to reduce your memory requirements or get more RAM. There is no "magic" that will let you put 12.8 GB of stuff into an 8 GB bag.

Comment: In general, his paging file will grow on its own. In a 64bit process, you get something like 15TB. Most "Out of memory" errors have nothing to do with how much RAM you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite a big array:

```
30 * 40 * 400 * 400 * 5 * (4 bytes) ~= 3.6GB total
```

Assuming you have that much free memory and are running a 64bit process (required for > 2/3GB), it's possible you are hitting a wall because arrays are laid out as contiguous blocks in memory.

In the example above using [30][40,400,400,5] you're asking the CLR to find 30 128Mb blocks of memory.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

You could try creating lists referencing smaller arrays, or simply declare it as a 'jagged' array to avoid the contiguous memory issue (at the cost of worst performance in dereferencing arrays of arrays).

i.e. float[30][40][400][400][5]

Comment: May I know how you init the List like what you mention?

Comment: That's not entirely true. He's defining an array of 30 multi-dimensional arrays, each of which is `40*400*400*5*(4 bytes)`, or 128 megabytes. So he needs 30 individual blocks of 128 megabytes. Each of those blocks has to be contiguous, but he doesn't need 3.6 GB contiguous.

Comment: @JimMischel i though it might have been treated differently for arrays of primitive types but some googling around confirms your point - have updated my answer

Comment: FWIW, you are generally limited to 2gb, even on 64bit. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: @EricLaw: Again, that limit only applies for a single allocation. Here we have 30 separate allocations of 128 MB, which is essentially what that `BigArray` does. And, of course, .NET 4.5 allows larger allocations with `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "again." His claim that gcAllowVeryLargeObjects fixes the issue suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an array?

I would create a class with a getter and setter. The internal storage can then use smaller arrays.

```
public class FiveDimensionalData<T> {
    private const int BucketSize = 16384; // keep object out of LOH
    private T[][] _buckets;
    private int _x, _y, _z, _u, _v;

    public FiveDimensionalData(int x, int y, int z, int u, int v) {
        if (x < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x");
        if (y < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y");
        if (z < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("z");
        if (u < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("u");
        if (v < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("v");

        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;
        _u = u;
        _v = v;

        long totalSize = ((long)x)*y*z*u*v;

        int totalBuckets = (int)(totalSize / BucketSize) + 1;
        _buckets = new T[totalBuckets][];

        for (int ii = 0; ii < totalBuckets; ++ii)
            _buckets[ii] = new T[BucketSize];
    }

    public T Get(int x, int y, int z, int u, int v) {
        long bucketIndex = Index(x, y, z, u, v); 

        int bucket = (int)(bucketIndex / BucketSize);
        int positionInBucket = (int)(bucketIndex % BucketSize);

        return _buckets[bucket][positionInBucket];
    }

    public void Set(int x, int y, int z, int u, int v, T value) {
        long bucketIndex = Index(x, y, z, u, v); 

        int bucket = (int)(bucketIndex / BucketSize);
        int positionInBucket = (int)(bucketIndex % BucketSize);

        _buckets[bucket][positionInBucket] = value;
    }

    private long Index(int x, int y, int z, int u, int v) {
        if (x < 0 || x > _x)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x");
        if (y < 0 || y > _y)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y");
        if (z < 0 || z > _z)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("z");
        if (u < 0 || u > _u)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("u");
        if (v < 0 || v > _v)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("v");

        long index = (long)x * _y * _z * _u * _v + 
                     (long)y * _z * _u * _v +
                     (long)z * _u * _v +
                     (long)u * _v +
                     (long)v;
        return index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Windows 32 bit (86x) than you have to check the memory size before adding a new element.

```
// Here you have to check that the current used memory in your process; this shall not exceed more than 2 GB;
// If you are using  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE than not exceed 4 GB
If (MemoryHelper.CanAllocateObject())
{
 // here add a new elements
}
```

To get the current process and use:
     Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
     proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s80a75e5%28VS.80%29.aspx